# Rolling Stock Position Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

Grateful for any help.

I have a data source which looks like below: Many customers, markets and products.

| ForecastShipmentDate | Customer | Market | SKU | ForecastType | ForecastName | 9Lc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | AnyCust | UK | 11111 | Shipment | ForecastX | 2 |
| 01/01/2021 | AnyCust | UK | 11111 | Depletion | ForecastX | 1 |
| 01/02/2021 | AnyCust | UK | 11111 | Shipment | ForecastX | 2 |
| 01/02/2021 | AnyCust | UK | 11111 | Depletion | ForecastX | 1 |
| 01/03/2021 | AnyCust | UK | 11111 | Shipment | ForecastX | 2 |
| 01/03/2021 | AnyCust | UK | 11111 | Depletion | ForecastX | 1 |
| 01/04/2021 | AnyCust | UK | 11111 | Shipment | ForecastX | 2 |
| 01/04/2021 | AnyCust | UK | 11111 | Depletion | ForecastX | 1 |
| 01/04/2021 | AnyCust | UK | 11111 | Stock | ForecastX | 10 |
| 01/05/2021 | AnyCust | UK | 11111 | Shipment | ForecastX | 2 |
| 01/05/2021 | AnyCust | UK | 11111 | Depletion | ForecastX | 1 |
| 01/06/2021 | AnyCust | UK | 11111 | Shipment | ForecastX | 2 |
| 01/06/2021 | AnyCust | UK | 11111 | Depletion | ForecastX | 1 |

For each forecast a customer will provide a stock position at the close of the previous month (this then becomes Aprils opening stock as shown above) and what I'm trying to do is create a rolling stock position.

So Stock  + Shipments - Depletions = Closing stock.

I have created a number of different measures but can't get the knack of this as May, June etc. don't have an opening stock to work with.

Effectively what I'm trying to create is:

Ignore months before stock date (April in this case)

- For April: Take the Stock position and add shipments minus depletions to create a closing stock
- For May: Take Aprils "closing stock" and add May's shipments minus May's depletions to create a May closing stock
- For June: Take May's "closing stock" and add June's shipments minus June's depletions to create a June - closing stock
- July, August, Sept...Dec

As there is only a stock position for April I'm tying myself up in knots a little and would appreciate any help with the correct formula.

Comment: Could you describe how you try to display the measure? Table/Matrix Viz; row/column headers, slicers. Also, if it is an aggregate measure (only year-month as row headers) between customers/markets/products, how do you decide which stock to choose from the different customers/markets/products?

Comment: Hey yes, display would probably be quite basic. A matrix just showing the position by month possibly a line graph as well. It would be filtered by Customer, Market or SKU these would be controlled through separate dimension tables/slicers

Comment: I'll receive a forecast in April, only an opening stock for April with shipments and depletions for all months.

The logic is relatively straightforward but the formulas causing a mental block.

The logic is...
Ignore everything before April
Take Aprils opening stock and add shipments minus depletions
This creates a "virtual opening stock" for May.
Take Mays "virtual opening stock" and add shipments minus depletions
repeat for all outlook months.

I'm trying to create is a "virtual opening stock" for all months starting from April where I have the actual opening stock.

Comment: I still don't understand how you would deal with the presence of multiple selected clients/ markets/SKUs. Possibly you restrict the slicers to a single selection but I will respond with a pattern that would meet basic requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I added a YearMonth column to iterate only at the month level:

[image]

The example data is:

[image]

And having disabled the Subtotals and hiding the Grand total headers I got this:

[image]

Making use of this:

```
Measure :=
VAR MaxFSD =
    MAX ( Forecasts[ForecastShipmentDate] )
VAR StockDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( Forecasts[ForecastShipmentDate] ),
        ALL ( Dates ),
        Forecasts[ForecastType] = "Stock"
    )
VAR StockRange =
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Dates[YearMonth] ),
        Dates[YearMonth]
            >= YEAR ( StockDate ) * 100
                + MONTH ( StockDate )
            && Dates[YearMonth]
                <= YEAR ( MaxFSD ) * 100
                    + MONTH ( MaxFSD )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( Forecasts[Market] ),
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( Forecasts[9Lc] ),
            ALL ( Dates ),
            StockRange,
            Forecasts[ForecastType] = "Stock"
        )
            + CALCULATE (
                SUM ( Forecasts[9Lc] ),
                ALL ( Dates ),
                StockRange,
                Forecasts[ForecastType] = "Shipment"
            )
            - CALCULATE (
                SUM ( Forecasts[9Lc] ),
                ALL ( Dates ),
                StockRange,
                Forecasts[ForecastType] = "Depletion"
            )
    )
```